# Scroll feature prevents unchecking Deform for many bones at once

Tags: rigging, interface, customization

I'm trying to uncheck Deform for many bones at once. To do this, I was told to use Alt Select. However, when I do that, the cursor becomes a scroll icon and won't affect the checkbox:

[image]

This happens in other panels, too:

[image]

How can I disable this scroll feature? Is there another way to disable Deform for all my selected bones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can press Alt+W to get the 'Disable Bone Options' menu and disable Deform for all the selected bones.

[image: Disable Bone Options menu]